# determining height to be set based on font size in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

In IOS, we have height and font size for UI label.
When I add a uilabel to the screen, I see a default height and font for it and height is always bit more than the font size to take care of ascenders and descenders. But when I increase the font size in design time, the height still remains at where it was when it was added to the screen. So, how to I decide during design time what is the appropriate height to be set if I change the font size to what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit the text of the label and press enter, it will take it's size

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Click your label in the canvas so that you get its resize handles. Then, from the menu bar, choose Editor > Size to Fit Content. The default shortcut is <kbd>⌘=</kbd>.